# SharePoint online Cross site lookup values

Tags: sharepoint

I'm looking for cross site lookup values from one site to another site in SharePoint Online. is it possible to achieve this? if yes, could you please guide me the steps to perform this task.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use list items values from one site as options in lookup column in a list on a different site, without any customization. I think what you could be looking for is term management and manage metadata columns. Term store management is something you create for a tenant level. In a very simple explanation you may think of it as a place to create global and hierarchical dictionaries made of terms and groups. Then in SharePoint list or library you may add a manage metadata column that will allow the users to pick values from a specified termstore. You may create this kind of column on any list and any site as terms are available on tenant level.

Please look more into the concept here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/managed-metadata

And here is an example how to create a manage metadata column -> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-managed-metadata-column-8fad9e35-a618-4400-b3c7-46f02785d27f

I hope this will be of any help.

---

#### Update

within term store you may create a nested structure grouping terms and then when user selects the value he may select from terms in this structure so it may be like a kind of cascading choice but presented differently. I am not sure if it will meet your needs
[image]

Comment: I used cascading dropdown in the existing list and i want to use the same lists in another site and similar functionality. wherein for any changes if i do change in one site it should apply to across other sites. not sure with Managed metadata this can be achievable

Comment: I was not aware of this cascading dropdowns you used. In termstore there is something similar but may provide a bit different user experience, please see the update. I would advice you to check it out yourself to check if it meets your needs. For sure it is something to consider

Comment: Thank you so much. will give a try but not sure whether the cascade dropdown functionality will work here